# Convolutional Autoencoder outputs black images

Tags: conv-neural-network, autoencoder, transfer-learning, resnet, image-classification

I need to train an autoencoder on Adaptiope dataset. I am using a ResNet18 backbone for my **encoder** part.
The issue I encounter is that even after many epochs, the reconstructed image is always completely black.

On the other hand, when I use a simpler Autoencoder **without** the resnet18 backbone, reconstructed images turn out close to what I need them to be.

I am trying to understand why is this the case. I am a novice in the field and still cannot grasp the problem. It looks like an architectural problem but I cannot wrap my head around it.

This is my "vanilla" Encoder, with no resnet18 backbone:

`

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 num_input_channels : int,
                 base_channel_size : int,
                 latent_dim : int
                 ):
        """
        Inputs:
            - num_input_channels : Number of input channels of the image. For CIFAR, this parameter is 3
            - base_channel_size : Number of channels we use in the first convolutional layers. Deeper layers might use a duplicate of it.
            - latent_dim : Dimensionality of latent representation z
            - act_fn : Activation function used throughout the encoder network
        """
        super().__init__()
        c_hid = base_channel_size
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(num_input_channels, c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), # 32x32 => 16x16
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Conv2d(c_hid, c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Conv2d(c_hid, 2*c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), # 16x16 => 8x8
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Conv2d(2*c_hid, 2*c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Conv2d(2*c_hid, 2*c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=2), # 8x8 => 4x4
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Flatten(), # Image grid to single feature vector
                    nn.Linear(351232, latent_dim))
        
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(latent_dim, 20*8)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)

    def forward(self, x):

      enc = self.layer1(x)
      lin_p = self.linear2(enc) 
      p = self.softmax(lin_p)
      return enc, p
```

`This is the Encoder with Resnet18 backbone:`

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 num_input_channels : int,
                 base_channel_size : int,
                 latent_dim : int
                 ):
        """
        Inputs:
            - num_input_channels : Number of input channels of the image. For CIFAR, this parameter is 3
            - base_channel_size : Number of channels we use in the first convolutional layers. Deeper layers might use a duplicate of it.
            - latent_dim : Dimensionality of latent representation z
            - act_fn : Activation function used throughout the encoder network
        """
        super().__init__()
        c_hid = base_channel_size
        self.fc_hidden1, self.fc_hidden2, self.CNN_embed_dim = 224, 768, 224

        # CNN architechtures
        self.ch1, self.ch2, self.ch3, self.ch4 = 16, 32, 64, 128
        self.k1, self.k2, self.k3, self.k4 = (5, 5), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3)      # 2d kernel size
        self.s1, self.s2, self.s3, self.s4 = (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)      # 2d strides
        self.pd1, self.pd2, self.pd3, self.pd4 = (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)  # 2d padding

        # encoding components
        model = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
        for param in model.parameters():
                    param.requires_grad = False
        modules = list(model.children())[:-1]      # delete the last fc layer.
        self.resnet_modules=modules
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*modules)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, self.fc_hidden1) 
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.fc_hidden1, momentum=0.01)
     
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.layer = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Flatten(), # Image grid to single feature vector
                    nn.Linear(224, latent_dim)) #8x224
        #self.flatten = nn.Flatten(), # Image grid to single feature vector
        #self.linear1 = nn.Linear(351232, latent_dim) 
        
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(latent_dim, 20*8) 
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)

    def forward(self, x):
      x = self.resnet(x)
      x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 512)
      x = self.fc1(x)
      x = self.bn1(x)
      x = self.relu(x)
      enc = self.layer(x)
      
      #x = self.fc2(x) 
      #x = self.bn(x)
     # enc = self.layer1(x)

      lin_p = self.linear2(enc) 
      p = self.softmax(lin_p)
      return enc, p
```

`The decoder is the same for both.`

```
class Decoder_N(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 num_input_channels : int,
                 base_channel_size : int,
                 latent_dim : int,
                 act_fn : object = nn.GELU):
        """
        Inputs:
            - num_input_channels : Number of channels of the image to reconstruct. For CIFAR, this parameter is 3
            - base_channel_size : Number of channels we use in the last convolutional layers. Early layers might use a duplicate of it.
            - latent_dim : Dimensionality of latent representation z
            - act_fn : Activation function used throughout the decoder network
        """
        super().__init__()
        c_hid = 224
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(latent_dim, 351232),
             nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(2*c_hid, 2*c_hid, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2), # 4x4 => 8x8
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(2*c_hid, 2*c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(2*c_hid, c_hid, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2), # 8x8 => 16x16
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(c_hid, c_hid, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(c_hid, 3, kernel_size=3, output_padding=1, padding=1, stride=2), # 16x16 => 32x32
            nn.Tanh() # The input images is scaled between -1 and 1, hence the output has to be bounded as well
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1, 28, 28)
        x = self.net(x)
        return x
```

`

num_input_channels : 224,
base_channel_size : 3
latent_dim : 64

I expected the "advanced" autoencoder to extract my features better, but apparently this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue: there were issues with the normalization of images and the BatchNorm layer. I accidentally used mean and std of ImageNet for the dataset instead of the correct ones. Additionally, during training I forgot to add regularizers for the different components of my loss, leading my model to learn literally nothing.